# JS Promise.all with document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, promise

I need to get a json file for some data and also wait for the dom to load (and use the json to populate a table). Is there a way to do both of these simultaneously?
Here's what I have now. Obviously, it is slow because it waits for the dom and then the get.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $.get(..., callback)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery AJAX functions return a promise (actually a jQuery `Deferred`, but they can be used similarly).

Start the AJAX request before waiting for the DOM to load, then process the result after.

```
let get_promise = $.get(...);
$(document).ready(() => {
  get_promise.then(callback)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use when

```
var d1 = $.Deferred();
var d2 = $.get(...)

$(document).ready(() => {
  d1.resolve();
})

$.when( d1, d2 ).done(function ( v1, v2 ) {
  console.log(v2);
});
```

but it would make more sense to use done() with the get call inside of the ready

```
var jqxhr = $.get( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
});

$(document).ready(() => {
  jqxhr.done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
  });
});
```